# Volume of the ellipsoid $(x+2y)^2+(x-2y+z)^2+3z^2=1$

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the ellipsoid $(x+2y)^2+(x-2y+z)^2+3z^2=1$, using integration.

It is clear that this is not centered at the origin. So, how do I find the limits for an integral? Any suggestion please. I have no clue at all to start.

Comment: Why is it clear that it is not centered at the origin?

Comment: @fibonatic: Because if it is centered at the origin then it should be of the form, $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=d$

Comment: Why not convert to spherical coordinates?

Comment: @KingDuken: It is not centered at the origin. So, how do you recognize the limits for spherical system? Can you explain please?

Comment: Try finding a coordinate system in which it *is* centered at the origin.

Comment: @amd: I tried it. That is the most difficult thing here.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta That form also has its principal axis aligned with the x, y and z axis. But if you would rotate that ellipse then you can get form as in your question. Only if one or more of the quadratic terms would contain a constant, then it would not be centered around the origin.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta is right—this ellipsoid *is* centered around the origin, but rotated.

Comment: @amd: How did you recognize it?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta There are no linear terms.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious change of variables: $x'=x+2y$, $y'=x-2y+z$, $z'=\sqrt3z$?

Comment: Oh, looks like there are a couple of answers that do this already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The volume is the integral of the function $1$ over the ellipsoid. You can evaluate it by changing variables to $X = x + 2y,\,\, Y = x - 2y + z,\,\,Z = \sqrt{3}z$.

In the new coordinates, one now has the sphere $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 1$, of volume
${\displaystyle {4 \pi \over 3}}$. One has to multiply this by the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant of the
coordinate change. The Jacobian matrix of the $(x,y,z)$ to $(X,Y,Z)$ coordinate change here is given by
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix} $$
The determinant of $M$ is readily computed to be $-4\sqrt{3}$. Since the
coordinate change goes in the opposite direction, we will divide by this quantity.

Hence the total volume of the ellispoid is ${\displaystyle {4 \pi \over 3} / 4\sqrt{3}= {\pi \over 3\sqrt{3}}}$.

Comment: Beat me to it :) Since the OP states that this was an exercise in change of variables, this looks like the sort of thing that the source was looking for.

Comment: +1 for giving an answer relevant to what the OP is looking for, rather than showing what you know.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: that sounds like "I don't want to learn anything new, just do my homeworks for free".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: This is not my homework. I am reading the section I mentioned these days, so i wanted to use what I read to solve an exercise under that section. Does it mean that I did not want to learn new things?? To understand your answer I need many more knowledge and I am not going to learn everything in a hurry.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: once upon a time, linear algebra was a pillar of integration. Anyway, don't mind, I am removing my answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: You have to understand that "it is useless to teach undergrad math to a grade 1 student".

Comment: Then I guess such grade-1 student is in the wrong place.

Comment: I wish good luck for your students!